# In graph theory, is there like a non-ended edge?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

My current work relates to graph theory. For edge in graph theory, there is a starting vertex for the edge and an ending vertex for the edge. I know the starting and ending vertex can be the same vertex. But is there like a non-ended edge? Like, we get the starting vertex, but the other end of the edge is connected to nothing. For example, in a set of triangular mesh, we can regard the triangle to be the vertex (element) and regard the edges of these triangles to be connections between 2 bounded triangles. But some boundary edges only belong to one triangle.

Comment: I've heard of infinite graphs, akin to endless recursion, but I can't think of any infinite edge examples. Can't quite think of a use case either... In your example I don't see any infinite edges, tbh.

Comment: AFAIK, Graph definition is structure amounting to a set of objects in which some pairs of the objects are in some sense "related". According to this edge define as relation between object. Therefor, having one-side-only-edge kind of contradict this definition

Comment: In your example, where the edges represent the face boundaries, there is an external (presumably non-triangular) face bounded by the exterior of the mesh; you can create this as a vertex and connect that via the exterior edges of the mesh to the triangular faces.